Seeking Fastest Hash-Based NoSQL Database: GDBM vs Kyoto Cabinet & Other Alternatives
Background
I'm currently researching fast, hash-based key-value NoSQL databases for my use case, which requires high performance. I was surprised by the limited availability of benchmarks, particularly for GDBM. Despite being a long-established library, I found little comparative data on its performance, especially against other key-value databases like Kyoto Cabinet.
Questions

Performance of GDBM vs Kyoto Cabinet: Has anyone come across reliable benchmarks that compare GDBM's speed to Kyoto Cabinet's? Specifically, I'm interested in ingestion and lookup speeds for large datasets.

Faster Alternatives: Are there any other key-value, hash-based NoSQL databases that you've found to outperform these two in terms of speed? If so, could you point me to specific benchmarks or sources?


Requirements
The database needs to meet the following criteria:

Corruption resistance: Safe from data corruption in case of power failure or unexpected shutdown.
Concurrency: Support for multiple users (multiple readers with one writer at the same time).
Capacity: Able to handle a few million key-value pairs efficiently.
Bindings: must have bindings for the C language.

Research
I've gathered some relevant links and partial benchmarks, but there's a gap in comprehensive or head-to-head comparisons between GDBM and other hash-based systems:

...benchmarks of some embedded databases with Python
Are there any known benchmarks/statistics on UnQLite?
Kyoto Cabinet ingestion rate measurement
HaloDB against RocksDB and KyotoCabinet
LevelDB vs Kyoto Cabinet my findings

I'm looking for data beyond these sources, particularly regarding hash engines, and would appreciate any insights or references to benchmarks that are directly related to GDBM, Kyoto Cabinet, or other alternatives.

Is there any reason why you don't do the benchmarks yourself?

"Able to handle a few million key-value pairs efficiently" - That's a small amount of data. Not sure why you wouldn't use a less exotic and more standard database system?

@mustaccio , now that I've reflected more on your suggestion, I think I might actually do the tests myself and share the results. The main reason I hadn’t done so earlier is that I was hoping others, with more experience and knowledge in this area, had already conducted similar tests. To be completely honest, I also felt a bit unmotivated to dive into it at first. That said, knowing how informative and technical StackExchange can be, I thought asking the question could help me learn more from others' insights while also contributing to the community with my question.

(tl;dr: Speed is my priority)
@J.D., I’d say it's just the bare minimum for my project. I’m still figuring out exactly what I need, though, since I’m fairly new to this. What I do know for certain is that speed is crucial for my use case, even if it means opting for something a bit more specialized rather than a standard solution.

@GiorgosXou Sure, but at a few million rows, especially if your use case is key-value based (ergo probably not reading many values at one given time), really any modern mainstream database system will be able to handle your use cases just as fast as any other (~sub-millisecond time). True even if your data was billions of rows, if I understand your use case correctly. These obscure specialized databases won't offer you anything better. It sounds like you're prematurely optimizing.
